# Word for single brush stroke

Tags: single-word-requests

As I understand the meaning of the term "brushstroke", it usually means continuous line painted with brush. Is there any word for especially one single touch brushstroke?

Comment: _light brushstroke_, perhaps

Comment: A brush stroke **is** one single touch, with the brush moving on the canvas or wall or whatever it is. Are you looking for a name for the mark made by a brush which **doesn't** move in that way? In which case, a speck, a fleck, a dot, a dab, a speckle, a freckle, a dab... You could try a thesaurus [https://www.lexico.com/synonyms/fleck].